# How to skip/block the before_request call in pytest for Python flask application?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, python-unittest

I have a sample flask application as below

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request()
def before_request():
   # Something
   if true
       return True
   else
       return False 

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Also I have a pytest for this

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    tester = app.test_client()
    yield tester

def test_index():
   response = client.get('/')
   assert response.status_code == 200
```

I want to write the test cases for my application.

Whenever I try to test the index ie / or any  endpoint it will goto before_request first  that it was my application design

Is there a way to skip the before_request in pytest?

So that i can test my functionality whether its working properly or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Ideally, you should put conditions inside `before_request()` on which cases it should be skipped, such as in the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_request) which is based on the presence of a key in session:

> ```py
> @app.before_request
> def load_user():
>     if "user_id" in session:
>         g.user = db.session.get(session["user_id"])
> ```

If that is done, we can then try to patch those objects in the condition (in the example above is `session`) to control whether it would be skipped or not.

**src.py**

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if "user_id" in session:
        return None  # Let's say we will skip if user_id is present
    print("Before request")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("Within index")
    return "Hello World!"
```

**test_src.py**

```
import pytest

from src import app


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    tester = app.test_client()
    yield tester


def test_index_mock_before_request(client, mocker):
    mocker.patch("src.session", {"user_id": None})  # Patch session to include "user_id" so that the before_request would be skipped

    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200


def test_index(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

### Solution 2

If changing the `before_request()` is not an option, an alternative solution (**not recommended** but would work) is to remove the unwanted `before_request` functions registered in the Flask-app object via its [before_request_funcs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_request_funcs).

**src.py**

```
...
# Same as above, just replace the following lines

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    print("Before request")
...
```

**test_src.py**

```
...
# Same as above, just replace the following lines

def test_index_mock_before_request(client, mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(app, "before_request_funcs", {})  # Remove all registered before_request functions so that they wouldn't be run

    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
...
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
..                                                                                            [100%]
============================================== PASSES ===============================================
__________________________________ test_index_mock_before_request ___________________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
Within index
____________________________________________ test_index _____________________________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
Before request
Within index
2 passed in 0.14s
```

- As you can see, with the patches, the code within `before_request()` wasn't executed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me the fixture for mocker.

Comment: Ohh I haven't included info about that. You have to run `pip install pytest-mock` https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/